# Set NetworkManager to ignore rfkill

Tags: wifi, drivers, hardware, networkmanager, network-interface

My notebook does not have a hardware button to disable wireless. But NetworkManager and rfkill see wireless as hard blocked. Wicd and iwconfig works well.

Is there any way to disable hard block check in driver or network manager?
Or make rfkill to show right state?

Driver is `ath9k`. Wireless card is `Qualcomm Atheros AR9565`

Comment: What you need is not to get NM to believe that the wifi is enabled, but to actually enable the wifi. Please tell us the output of `rfkill list` (install the `rfkill` package if necessary, though maybe you can use systemd's built-in support if you're using systemd) and `find /sys -name rfkill`. What distribution are you using and what distribution?

Comment: @Gilles, rfkill report that cards are hardblocked, debian jessie, lenovo g50-30

Comment: phy0 is not blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm blacklisted `ideapad_laptop` module and now seems to all works fine!

```
echo blacklist ideapad_laptop > /etc/modprobe.d/bad_rfkill.conf
depmod -ae
update-initramfs -u
```

And rebooted. What i disabled with removing this module except wireless interface?